# Expectation of Joint density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given two random variable X and Y and their joint density function is
 `f(x,y) = 8xy` `0<x<1, 0<y<x`
Find expectation of X and Y.
I have problem in taking limit of x and y in marginal distribution and in solving expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limits are $0<x<1$ and  $0<y<x$.

The marginal distribution of $X$ is

$$f_X(x)=\int_{0}^{x} 8xy \, dy$$

$y$ is greater than $0$ and smaller than $x$.

And $$f_Y(y)=\int_{y}^{1} 8xy \, dx$$

$x$ is greater than $y$ and smaller than $1$.

You can make a sketch.

[image]

**Remark**

$0<x<1$ and  $0<y<x$ can be combined to $0<y<x<1$

Comment: How to find expectation of X and Y .?

Comment: @user5516017 $E(X)=\int_{0}^1 x\cdot f_X(x) \, dx$. Similar for $E(Y)$

Comment: @user5516017 Does it work ? A reply would by kindful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell mw what will be the limits in case of expectation of Y and how to know the limits in E(Y)? In my textbook the limit in case of expectation is given from 0 to 1 but 'y' varies from 0 to x.

Comment: @user5516017 The limits for calculating $E(Y)$ are $0$ and $1$ as well. The pdf of $Y$ is $f_Y(y)=4\cdot  y\cdot  (1-y^2)$ for $0<y<1$. In case of the marignal pdf the limits of $y$ do not depend on $x$, et vice versa.  Thus $E(Y)=\int_0^1 4\cdot  y^2\cdot  (1-y^2) \, dy$